# JSP Fragments: Which tags are reduplicated at the top

Tags: ajax, dojo, jsp-fragments

I have a JSP page which has the following tags prior to the `<html>` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Which of these need to be carried over into a JSP/HTML fragment that will be pulled into the page via AJAX call.  (Specifically, a Dojo xhrGet... but I'm not sure that's relevant.)  If more environmental information is required to answer this, please let me know and I will gladly expand this question.

Comment: The answer, as always, is it depends. I would lose the XML prolog, and lose the DOCTYPE. As both are only sensible at the parent page level, for your usage.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm sure I need the taglib because we are using JSTL core tags.  If my page encoding for the fragment is the same as the parent page, can I omit the @page tag and the fragment will inherit encoding from the parent?

Comment: No, the fragment also needs to let the browser know which encoding is used to encode it. Otherwise the fragment's text content can be decoded incorrectly by the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.  This is what we went with.  It works fine:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```